# How would i go about writing this equation in matrix form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

so I have an equation that I am able to solve with WolframAlpha, but now I want to implement it into a python program and solve it with numpy. For this I have to write it in matrix form. I know how to write simple equation systems in matrix form but I have no clue how to do it with this one.
$$(x-x_A)^2 + (y-y_A)^2 + (z-z_A)^2 = r_A^2$$
$$(x-x_B)^2 + (y-y_B)^2 + (z-z_B)^2 = r_B^2$$
$$(x-x_C)^2 + (y-y_C)^2 + (z-z_C)^2 = r_C^2$$
The equation should be solved for $x, y, z$
I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Matrices are for linear systems. This is non-linear in $x, y, z$, but somehow linear in the squares of the differences. Thus you cannot use matrices alone to solve for $x, y, z.$ An iterative method, such as Newton's method, can be used to solve this system.

Comment: You can write it in terms of dot products vectors, which are kinds of matrices.

Comment: Geometrically, the solution is the intersection of three spheres. That's not a problem you can solve with matrices.

Comment: Actually, although the system in not linear, it reduces to a linear one by subtraction, since all quadratic terms in $x,y,z$ are eliminated.

Comment: A quadratic system can be written in matrix form as $x^\top Ax=b$ .

Comment: @lhf : If you subtract $x^2+y^2+z^2$ from both sides, you've just moved those terms to the other side. They can't disappear.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, I meant, subtracting two equations.

Comment: @lhf : Look at the various solutions for intersections of spheres. How are you going to get circles of points as solutions of linear equations, for example?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\q#1#2{\LR{#1-#2}^T\LR{#1+#2}}
\def\qq#1#2#3#4{#1^2-#2^2+#3^2-#4^2}
\def\x{x}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$For typing convenience, introduce the variables
$$\eqalign{
&\x = \m{x\\y\\z}\quad
&a = \m{x_A\\y_A\\z_A} \quad
&b = \m{x_B\\y_B\\z_B} \quad
&c = \m{x_C\\y_C\\z_C} \\
&&\,p \;=\; \,r_A &\,q \;=\; \,r_B &\,r \;=\; \,r_C \\
}$$
Subtraction eliminates the quadratic terms and leaves 3 equations for the 3 components of $\x$
$$\eqalign{
2\LR{a-b}^T\x &= {\qq abqp} \\
2\LR{b-c}^T\x &= {\qq bcrq} \\
2\LR{c-a}^T\x &= {\qq capr} \\
}$$
which can be put into matrix form
$$\eqalign{
E &= \m{2\LR{a-b}^T \\ 2\LR{b-c}^T \\ 2\LR{c-a}^T}\qquad
f = \m{\qq abqp\\\qq bcrq\\\qq capr}
\qiq E\x &= f
}$$

Comment: As a side remark, the f-term should rather include squared norms of vectors a,b,c  which is not obvious from th notations.